# How to add "Sign in With Apple" In ionic 3 Application?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

Does anyone know how to add "Sign in with Apple" in Ionic 3 IOS Application as Apple is rejecting the applications containing third parties login libraries but not including "Sign In With Apple".

Comment: Same question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57825306/how-to-enable-sign-in-with-apple-id-in-ionic-3-application/60132953#60132953

Answer (score 0):

You can implement as below

install cordova plugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple
npm install @ionic-native/sign-in-with-apple



 declare var cordova: any; //Add this line right below the imports

///

SignInApple(){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cordova.plugins.SignInWithApple.signin({ 
        requestedScopes: [0, 1] 
    }, (succ) => { 
        // If you want to use firebase then use below
        var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com').credential(succ.identityToken);
        this.afAuth.auth.signinWithCredential(provider).then(result => {
        }).catch( error => {
            reject( error.message || error );
        })
        // If you want your own auth validation method you can add it here.
    },(err) => { // changed here too, for consistence
        reject("Apple login failed");
    })
})
}
```