# Sign In With Apple - Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, sign-in-with-apple

Am trying to implement sign in with apple on my ionic 3 project using the following plugin and wrapper

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple
npm i --save @ionic-native/sign-in-with-apple
```

Implementation as described on the plugin docs

```
import { SignInWithApple, AppleSignInResponse, AppleSignInErrorResponse, ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest } from '@ionic-native/sign-in-with-apple/ngx';


  constructor(private signInWithApple: SignInWithApple) { }


    this.signInWithApple.signin({
      requestedScopes: [
        ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest.ASAuthorizationScopeFullName,
        ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest.ASAuthorizationScopeEmail
      ]
    })
    .then((res: AppleSignInResponse) => {
      // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/verifying_a_user
      alert('Send token to apple for verification: ' + res.identityToken);
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((error: AppleSignInErrorResponse) => {
      alert(error.code + ' ' + error.localizedDescription);
      console.error(error);
    });
```

The following error is thrown during cordova ios  build process

```
typescript: node_modules/@ionic-native/sign-in-with-apple/ngx/index.d.ts, line: 6 
        Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts. 

   L5:  export declare class ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest {
   L6:      static readonly ASAuthorizationScopeFullName = 0;
   L7:      static readonly ASAuthorizationScopeEmail = 1;
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

```
tsc -v 
Version 3.8.3
```

Answer (score 2):

this work for me:

1. install:

`ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/twogate/cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple.git`

2. declare var in your component

`declare var cordova:any; // global`

```
cordova.plugins.SignInWithApple.signin(
    { requestedScopes: [0, 1] },
    function(response){
      console.log(response)
      alert(JSON.stringify(response))
    },
    function(err){
      console.error(err)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
}
```

I hope this solution can help someone.

IMPORTANT --> Test in device

Answer (score 1):

I tried your solution and faced the same issues with me.

my implementation for login with Apple ID works well with me ionic 3.

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple

```
//before @component add declare var cordova: any;

        async loginWithAppleID() {
        await cordova.plugins.SignInWithApple.signin(
          {requestedScopes: [0, 1]},
          (succ) => {
            //get email and full name from Apple ID
            console.log(succ)
            let userData = {
              name: succ.fullName.givenName + ' ' + succ.fullName.familyName,
              email: succ.email,
            };
    // this.AuthApi;
          },
          (err) => {
            console.error(err)
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
          }
        )
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error.

The error comes from the [small changes in this commit](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/commit/87644400871a827b1af990fa17eb611e7e488d82#diff-a2531cb5c7ba993a5b474905360a3418).

Using the version before that commit solved the problem for me. If you're ok with reverting to a previous version, try this:

```
npm install @ionic-native/sign-in-with-apple@5.16.0
```

After that `ionic build` should succeed. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Got this error while trying to implement apple sign in for my Ionic3 app. Adding sign-in-with-apple@5.16.0 did not address the issue. Tried below option and ionic build was successful.

Add skipLibCheck so that it will skip type checking of all declaration files (*.d.ts) on compilation.

Example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl":  "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@environment": ["config/config.prod"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
...
...
```

Comment: What error did you get ?

Comment: Same as mentioned in the original question typescript: node_modules/@ionic-native/sign-in-with-apple/ngx/index.d.ts, line: 6 
        Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts. 

   L5:  export declare class ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest {
   L6:      static readonly ASAuthorizationScopeFullName = 0;
   L7:      static readonly ASAuthorizationScopeEmail = 1;