# How to implement Apple SignIn with Cordova and a PHP backend (no FireBase)

Tags: php, ios, cordova, authentication

Good morning to everyone.
I'm trying to find some solutions by myself for the last 5 days, but at the end I had to to ask for a help to you.
I made a mobile application using Ionic (**Cordova**) with Angular and I've already correctly published it on the Google Play Store. The problem is now with Apple Store because it asks to implement a "**Apple SignIn**" button: from April 2020 it looks that if you have third-part login (I've Facebook login) you have to use the Apple SignIn too.
I've found around internet few interesting solutions, but all of them are using Firebase as a backend and I've used a **personal PHP backend** on my server.

**SOLUTION 1: cordova-plugin-apple-login**
Taking the first solution as example, there is a [nice tutorial](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2020/01/tutorial-sign-in-with-apple-siwa-and-ionic-cordova-angularfire-firebase.html) that teaches how to implement the plugin, but it uses Firebase.
Installation:

```
npm i cordova-plugin-apple-login
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-apple-login
```

Implementation:

```
declare var SignInWithApple: any;
```

Fully code:

```
   SignInWithApple.request({requestedScopes: [ SignInWithApple.Scope.Email, SignInWithApple.Scope.FullName ]})
    .then((appleCredential) => {
      const credential =  new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com').credential(appleCredential.identityToken);
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Login successful');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        alert('error:' + JSON.stringify(error));
      });
    });
```

**SOLUTION 2: cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple**
Taking for second solution as example, there is a [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57825306/how-to-enable-sign-in-with-apple-id-in-ionic-3-application) here in Stack Overflow that teaches how to implement the plugin, but it also uses Firebase.
Installation:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple
npm i --save @ionic-native/sign-in-with-apple
```

Implementation:

```
import { SignInWithApple, AppleSignInResponse, AppleSignInErrorResponse, ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest } from '@ionic-native/sign-in-with-apple';
```

Fully code:

```
async loginWithApple(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      try {
        const appleCredential: AppleSignInResponse = await SignInWithApple.signin({
          requestedScopes: [
            ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest.ASAuthorizationScopeFullName,
            ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest.ASAuthorizationScopeEmail
          ]
        });
        const credential = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com').credential(
          appleCredential.identityToken
        );
        this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
          .then((res) => {
            console.log('Login successful', res);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }
```

**WHAT I'M SEARCHING FOR**
As you can see in both solutions there is FireBase as a backend validation, but I'm searching a code to extract and save the 2 tokens (**Name** and **Email**) in a variable to post later in my php backend for the validation.
It wouldn't be so difficult I think, but I'm doing a lot of efforts on it and I can't find a good solution.
For *Facebook login* I'm using a code like the below one to extract and save the 2 variables... and I would like to do the same with Apple instead to use Firebase.

```
getUserDetail(userid: any) {
    this.fb.api('/' + userid + '/?fields=id,email,name,picture', ['public_profile'])
      .then(res => {
        this.users = res;
        this.emailFB = this.users['email'];
        this.usernameFB = this.users['name'];
        this.checkEmail(this.emailFB); //pass the email to do what I need in my PHP backend
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Have you find an answer? i have some problem....

Comment: No, still nothing

Comment: Have you found solution??

Answer (score 0):

This is a native PHP - without any framework, you can customize it in any frame work.

https://gist.github.com/ameen-sarsour/e14a1d5bae5b61080dfdd5b1430c3e10